# How do I create a jquery function that will override my css hover while javascript is enabled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

I have built a drop down menu in pure css and it works perfectly. Right now it only works when hovered over. Hovering over #headerNav causes the menu to my .dropdownMenu to drop down and as soon as cursor is taken away from dropdownMenu or the #headerNav the menu disappears.

Because I want users with js enabled to have a better experience, I've decided to use some jquery to get the same effect as [**click here**](http://aext.net/2009/08/perfect-sign-in-dropdown-box-likes-twitter-with-jquery/). Which basically keeps the drop down menu open after a click and click only not hovering.

By default I have set .dropdownMenu to "display: none" and then to show the drop down menu I have something like this:

```
#headerNav:hover .dropdownMenu {

        display:block;


        //more code


}
```

**Here is my html:**

```
<header>
  <div id='headerContent'>
    <div id='LogoHolder'>
    </div>
    <nav id='headerNav'>
      <ul>
        <li id='photoThumbnail'></li>
        <li id='currentUser'>
          <ul class="dropdownMenu">
            <li>link1</li>
            <li>link2</li>
            <li>link3</li>
            <li>link4</li>
            <li>link5</li>
            <li>link6</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

I've been experimenting for 2 days now and can't seem to come up with a way of doing this. I'd appreciate some help with clear examples. Thanks

Kind regards

Comment: Hope so this will help you, 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754546/can-i-disable-a-css-hover-effect-via-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most elegant way to deal with javascript enabled/disabled is to add :

```
<html class='no-js'>
```

then removing the class with Javascript.

So, in your case, you would use

```
.no-js #headerNav:hover .dropdownMenu {
        display:block;
}
```

to target only users with javascript disabled.

See : http://paulirish.com/2009/avoiding-the-fouc-v3/ for more details.

Comment: Great solution seeing as I already use modernizr. Now I can take care of the js without worrying about the hover affect because it only kicks in if js is disabled.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of targeting your nav by it's ID, add a class to it, say `hover-nav` and update your CSS accordingly:

`.hover-nav:hover .dropdownMenu`

Then in your javascript remove the css class from the `ul`

`$(#headerNav').removeClass('hover-nav');`

and use your click to show plugin as you normally would.

Comment: The first part worked for stopping the the dropdown showing on hover. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Nathan hit it on the head. I'll go ahead and paste the code, since I was already nearly finished with it.

**CSS**

```
#headerNav .hideable{ display:none; }
#headerNav:hover .hideable{ display:block; }​
```

**HTML** (just add `hideable` to your `UL`)

```
<ul class="dropDownMenu hideable">
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.hideable').hide().removeClass('hideable');

$('#headerNav').click( function(){
    $(this).find('.dropDownMenu').slideToggle();
});​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

*Replace above with this jQuery to add the ability to close the menu if anywhere else is clicked*.

```
$('.hideable').hide().removeClass('hideable');

$('#headerNav').click( function(e){
    $(this).find('.dropDownMenu').slideToggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
});​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

$('html').click( function(e){
    $('.dropDownMenu').slideUp();
});
```

Comment: I cleaned up the fiddle a bit to add attach the actions to `currentUser` instead of `headerNav`.

Comment: I'll give this a try and report back. I've looked at the jfiddle link and wondering if there is a way to make the menu also disappear if any where on the screen is clicked too and not just the actual button?

Comment: I'll also need the actions on headerNav instead of current user because headerNav is like a wrapper for holding the current users username and a thumbnail photo of them. When it's scrolled over it lights up like a big button and the whole area is clickable rather than just the users username.

Comment: Put `headerNav` back on jsfiddle, and added the code required to "close if anywhere else is clicked" to both jsfiddle and above answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is `.dropdownMenu`
Your Html is `class="drop DownMenu"`

**CSS is case sensitive.**

Comment: Hi corrected it, but this was an old copy and pasted version of the code I'm currently using with the correction. Thanks for the spot though.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#headerNav .dropDownMenu').hover(function() {
    $(this).show();
  });

  $('*:not(#headerNav .dropDownMenu)').click(function() {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $("#headerNav .dropDownMenu").hide();
  });
});
```