# CSS cancel property by overriding class

Tags: css

I have following html:

```
    <div class="red placeholder"></div>
    <div class="blue placeholder"></div>
    <div class="green placeholder"></div>
```

and CSS:

```
 .placeholder {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.placeholder:hover {
    background-color: gray;
}
.red {
    background-color: red;
}
.blue {
    background-color: blue;
}
.green {
    background-color: green;
}
```

I should not change initial placeholder declaration(s) and I don't want DIVs to change colour on hover.
Is there any way I can override *placeholder* class to "cancel" or turn off that hover property?

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8QJEq/4/

Comment: can you be more specific???you said "I don't want DIVs to change colour on hover. "...but your declaring `placeholder:hover`....

Comment: That's a duplicate of: [Can I disable a CSS :hover effect via JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754546/can-i-disable-a-css-hover-effect-via-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

That was really a good question, since am not able to work out any easier way than this, you can check out my solution

```
div[class="red placeholder"]:hover {
    background-color: red;
}

div[class="blue placeholder"]:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}

div[class="green placeholder"]:hover {
    background-color: green;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8QJEq/9/)

Explanation: What we are doing here is, we are selecting the elements having a combination of 2 classes, and than we use the same color on hover, which is their default `background-color`, so inshort, this won't take out the hover, it does hover, but because of the same background color, you won't see any change.

Comment: @thgaskell got some habit to overthink :D

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to avoid targeting the elements in the first place if at all possible.

If that's not possible, you could just declare the hover state with each color. As long as `.color:hover` is declared after `.placeholder:hover` it will override it since they share the same [specificity](http://iamacamera.org/default.aspx?id=95).

[jsfiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/8QJEq/17/)

#### CSS

```
.color, .color:hover { background-color: color; }
```

---

Though I wouldn't recommend it, but it sounds like you don't want divs with color classes to not change `background-color` you could also just declare the rules as `!important`. But this would only be a last resort option since you wouldn't be able to easily override the `background-color` again.

[jsfiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/8QJEq/16/)

#### CSS

```
.color { background-color: color !important; }
```