# How to disable hover for input type of file

Tags: jquery, angularjs, html

I have a HTML form and I am using an input of type "file". This gives me a browse button to upload a file. When I chose a file and click on save the browse button should be disabled. I have used jquery to disable the browse button. Now even after it is disabled and I hover over it the color of the button changes. So could anyone let me know how to remove the hover property for this button using jquery? I want to disable the hover property only after the user clicks save. Below is the code HTML code for the browse button.

```
<input type="file" id="fileUpload" accept="text/csv" 
       title="Browse" ng-disabled="fileInMemory"/>
```

Comment: Doesn't have a hover state for me: http://jsfiddle.net/d63bfv47/

Comment: I think there is some style sheet being applied to it which is getting the hover property for it. Could you let me know how I could disable it using jquery. Initially when the page loads I need the hover functionality but after the save button is clicked I want it to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
<style>

  input[type="file"]:hover{

  /* your css value */

 }
</style>
```

Comment: I want to remove the hover property of the button using jquery and only when a certain action occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Try change `ng-disabled` to `disabled`, like

```
<input type="file" id="fileUpload" accept="text/csv" title="Browse" disabled/>
```

And you can change 'disable' option using

```
$("#fileUpload").prop('disabled', true); // Off
$("#fileUpload").prop('disabled', false); // On
```

You can read the answer to similar question [How disable hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754546/can-i-disable-a-css-hover-effect-via-javascript)

Comment: I used $("#fileUpload").attr("disabled", '');. This works fine,the button is disabled but the color changes when I hover over it.

Comment: Try use my example for disable and enable input

Answer (score 0):

You can also use vanilla javascript doesn't give any hover effects whatsoever:

http://jsfiddle.net/xdrLeh5p/

```
<button id="btn" type="submit" disabled>disable/enable</button>

<button id="btnDisable">disable again</button>
```

JS

```
function enable () {
    document.getElementById('btn').removeAttribute('disabled');
}

document.getElementById('btnDisable').onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('btn').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');

}
enable();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the hover by adding an inline style like:

```html
<input style={{display: "none"}} onChange={(e) => handleChangeFile(e.target.files[0])} />
```

this solution is found in reactjs inline css