# Programatically disable hover on all elements of an HTML document

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to programatically disable `:hover` in my whole HTML document and all child elements using Javascript, without using classes or jQuery ?

Comment: you can use all selector but support is limited https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all

Comment: I think this is already answered
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754546/can-i-disable-a-css-hover-effect-via-javascript

Comment: @FelipeM Ehhh kind of, that is using classes, and you don't know what to *not* do on all dom elements, unless you go through and document every single thing that happens on hover and undo it in your new hover rule, which I think is going against what the OP wants

Comment: @mhodges it's probably the best basis for an answer though. Really, this is what I'd consider an unnatural act.

Comment: @Pointy This the solution to that question uses classes - this question specifically asks for a solution that does not use classes. Please consider re-opening

Comment: @mhodges well that's a good point, but I fear that the real answer then is "no".

Comment: @Pointy Agreed, I think the answer is no.

Comment: @mhodges I wonder if it'd work to throw up an absolutely-positioned `<div>` with a transparent background over the whole page? I think that would block `:hover`, but it would of course also block all other page interactions.

Comment: @Pointy Right, which would essentially be like doing `pointer-events: none`, unfortunately, I think it would have unintended consequences