# :focus is not working in dropdown list in some browsers

Tags: html, css, mobile, menu, dropdown

I'm trying to create a mobile vertical dropdown menu but I'm having an issue with showing the items of the sub-menu by using `:focus` for both .

I found a workaround by using `:focus` for sub-menu and `:focus-within` for its items .

This solution is working and showing the sub-menu items for Google Chrome only while other browsers like Samsung internet and UC browser are not showing any except the `:focus` of sub-menu.

I found another solution by using `:hover` for both and it's working for almost all browsers.

I have two questions:

- Why it was working only with chrome only?
- How do I use `:focus` for both the sub-menu and its items?

CSS used :

```css
.main-nav a {
 color:black;
 display: block;
 padding: 10px 3px 10px 3px;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'hayah';
    border-radius: 25px;
    transition: border-radius 0.2s ease-in;

}
.main-nav a:hover {
    background:#D7D7D7;
    border-radius:25px 25px 0 0; 
    -webkit-transition: border-radius 0.1s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: border-radius 0.1s ease-in;
    -o-transition: border-radius 0.1s ease-in;
    transition: border-radius 0.1s ease-in;  
    display: block;
    }
    
.main-nav-ul ul { 
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0; 
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden; 
    background-color: #D9D9D9;
    color: black;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    border-radius: 0 0 25px 25px;
    font-size: 12px;
    
    }
    
    
.main-nav-ul li:hover ul {  
    opacity: 1 !important;
    max-height: 400px !important;
    color: black;
    background-color: #E2E2E2;
    display: block;
    
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its hard to know what answer would work best for this situation without seeing how you implemented your HTML. `:focus-within` is not supported well: https://caniuse.com/#search=focus-within. Without seeing anything else I'm thinking maybe you would use JS to add and remove `:hover`/`:focus` like this answer: [Can I disable a CSS :hover effect via JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754546/can-i-disable-a-css-hover-effect-via-javascript). That way when you are not displaying sub-items you can get not use their hover effects.

Comment: Actually i was going to add the html but it's too dirty and cannot be understood ! I added a lot of styles that may confuse who is gonna read it .