# How to change a <a> tag color when I click on it and it doesn't change until I change my URL

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

What i'm trying to do is basically keep the color of an link when I click on it, hovering the navbar link makes it greyish, and when I click on it and while it stays on the URL i want to keep it a different color.
I'm using `react-router-dom` for the Link component

```
         <nav>
          <ul className="nav-wrapper">
            <li>
              <Link className="link" to="/">
                Home
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link className="link" to="/gallery">
                Gallery
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link className="link" to="/about">
                About
              </Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
```

I don't really know what to use here, i don't know if I should use a useState to try and change it when I click on it or change it on CSS, any tips are appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I disable a CSS :hover effect via JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754546/can-i-disable-a-css-hover-effect-via-javascript)

Comment: @Spectric unless I've misunderstood, OP wants to modify the `:hover`, `:active`, etc css attributes of their links. The answer I linked includes plan CSS solutions as well .

Comment: Please check my code, I think you store the active's component's number.

Comment: Thanks y'all for the help but Angel Martinez comment helped me, he used the same lib that I'm using in my project to change the Link to a NavLink, just a different Component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`react-router-dom` has an additional component called `NavLink` to which you can pass an additional prop called `activeClassName`. This will allow you to give custom styles to your active link.

example:

```
<NavLink to="/faq" activeClassName="selected">
  FAQs
</NavLink>
```

This component will replace all of your `Link` components in your navigation.

Answer (score 2):

( I didn't understand your question well so I did both)
Ok! Try this to change an unvisited link (CSS)
`a:link { color: what color you want; }`

Use this to change a visited link (CSS)'
`a:visited { color: what color you want; }`

Code example:

```css
a:active {
  color: green;
}
a:visited {
color: purple;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"> This link will change color<a>
```

> Please mark an answer if you found one.

Answer (score 1):

use the `:active` psudo selector. [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active)

Answer (score 1):

```
const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState(0);

        <nav>
          <ul className="nav-wrapper">
            <li>
              <Link className={`link ${selectedItem===0?'active':''}`}  to="/" onClick={()=>setSelectItem(0)}>
                Home
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link className={`link ${selectedItem===1?'active':''}`} to="/gallery" onClick={()=>setSelectItem(1)}>
                Gallery
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link className={`link ${selectedItem===2?'active':''}`} to="/about" onClick={()=>setSelectItem(2)}>
                About
              </Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
```

and then you can write on CSS,

```
 li .active{
     color: #your color;
 }
```